# Using multiple methods to create a simple calculator

Tags: c#, methods

I wrote out a simple calculator that uses multiple methods.
This is what I wrote out, but is there a better/more efficient way to write this code?
Suggestions would be helpful.

I want to use multiple methods and have everything visible in the main method.  I know it looks silly and can be done in a much more simple way, but I'm trying to explain this to people who are new to C# and are beginning to learn about methods.

```
{
        Console.WriteLine("Please input two numbers");
        int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int answer1 = Sum(num1, num2);
        int answer2 = Sub(num1, num2);
        int answer3 = Mult(num1, num2);
        double answer4 = Div(num1, num2);
        Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0}\n"+"Difference: {1} \n"+"Multiplication: {2} \n"+"Division: {3} \n", answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4);
    }

    public static int Sum(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    public static int Sub(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 - num2;
    }
    public static int Mult(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 * num2;
    }
    public static double Div(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 / num2;
    }


}
```

Comment: If you're looking for a "generic" method that varies based on operation, there is no such capability in c#.

Comment: Since they are new to c#, your implementation seems to be as simple as it gets.

Comment: You might add a method that gets an integer from the user (and continues to prompt them if the input is not a valid int) rather than blindly calling `Convert.ToInt32` on an unknown string (which will throw an exception on invalid input).

Comment: You also might want to validate that `num2` is not `0` in the `Div` method before blindly dividing by that number and encountering an exception.

Comment: Also the naming conventions might be improved to be more consistent with each other. Either `Sum` should be `Add`, or: `Sub` sould be `Diff`, `Mult` should be `Product`, and `Div` should be `Quotient`

Comment: Also you might just show calling `Console.WriteLine` multiple times rather than concatenating strings that end in the `'\n'` character.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small menu to choose what you want to do.

The following code is a code example, and you can refer to it.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a = string.Empty;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please input two numbers");
                int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please choose the following you want to do");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Add");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Minus");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Mult");
                Console.WriteLine("4. Div");
                int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (number)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Your result is" + Add(num1, num2));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Your result is" + Minus(num1, num2));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Your result is" + Mult(num1, num2));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Your result is" + Div(num1, num2));
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Please input again");
                        break;
                }
                a = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            while (a == "y");
        }

        public static int Add(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return num1 + num2;
        }
        public static int Minus(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return num1 - num2;
        }
        public static int Mult(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return num1 * num2;
        }
        public static double Div(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return num1 / num2;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The only possible improovement I could think off, is making those operators. But the existing Operators for Int alraedy cover all those cases and it [only works for your self-created types anyway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading).

As you are on the console. A do...while loop with a swtich/case as menu might be usefull for the programm flow. But not anything else I can think off.

Math is even one of the rare examples where static methods are not missplaced/overused.

Only a small terminology nitpick: Those are functions, not methods:

- functions return a value
- methods do not

However I have not see a langauge that actually differentaites between the two in ages. Delphi or VB might have this Keyword distinction.

Comment: Arguably, C# has it with the `Action` and `Func` delegates :)